# How to get a result from a void method from another class

Tags: java, methods, void

In **Class1** we have a method:

```
 public void check(String username, String password) {

   if (username and password are correct) {
         message = "checked"; 
   } else
   {
     message = "not checked";
   }
}
```

In **Class2** we have a method doPost and then we do this :

```
Class1 cl = new Class1();
cl.open();
cl.check(username,password);
cl.close()
```

In class Error I would like to show the message, which is in Class1. Maybe      with one Dispatcher? Which is the most efficiency way to make it?

Answer (score 2):

Surely there are much better ways for that, but if you don't want to change your solution as you are setting a message in *Class1*, you should be able to access to that message in *Class2*, so create *getter* and *setter* for the message variable and access the message via getter(and setters):

in **Class1**:

```
public String setMessage(String message){
   this.message=message;
}
public String getMessage(){
   return message;
}

public void check(String username, String password) {

   if (username and password are correct) {
         message = "checked"; 
   } else
   {
     message = "not checked";
   }
}
```

in `Class2`:

```
Class1 cl = new Class1();
cl.open();
cl.check(username,password);
cl.close();
out.println(cl.getMessage());//or anything else(you have access to generated  message)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can throw an exception in check() if the check fails.

Comment: That will work, but in my opinion, exceptions should be reserved for unexpected occurrences. A user entering an incorrect username or password is very much expected, and a method `check` whose sole purpose is to look for that occurrence should have a better way of signalling that it occurred.